# Marionette CompositeView in the select>option context

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to set up a simple Marionette's `CompositeView`. Here's what I want in the end:

```
%select#target-id
  %option{:value => "#{@id}"} = @name
  %option{:value => "#{@id}"} = @name 
  etc
```

In my `CompositeView` I specify the `childViewContainer: select` and I need to display both @name (for the readability) and @id (for the related event) in the options of this select. Due to the nature of default div element I can to speficfy `tagName` as `option` in my `ItemView`:

```
class New.TargetView extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "path/to/template"
    tagName: 'option'
```

And in the template I can pass only the content of to-be-created option element: `= @name`. This works fine, Marionette creates an option element for each model and populates it with the name of the model. The problem is that I don't know how to pass an attributes as well, since I can't specify an attribute of the element that hasn't been created yet.

I've also tried to set an `attributes` property on the `ItemView` like this:

```
attributes:
    value: "#{@id}"
```

And it technically works: the options are populated with the `value=""` attribute, but the content is undefined. Please  advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about part when you use `attributes`. You should pass hash or function that will return hash as stated in [Backbone view.attributes docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes).

```
attributes:
    value: "#{@id}"
```

In old money it works like this. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtqcnur2/1/).

```
attributes: function () {
    return {
        value: this.model.id
    };
}
```

Comment: I've managed to get around by forcing unwrapping of the element using `@$el.unwrap()`, but this is much more cleaner and it turns it was obvious all along. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`CompositeView` and `ItemView` are views that require a Marionette collection and model, respectively. When you create a `CompositeView` you pass a collection of models, each of which will be passed to the corresponding `ItemView`.

My guess is that it's not a problem with the template but with how you are setting up the data. As far as I know, there is no `attributes` option for `ItemView`, you have to either initialize the `CompositeView` with a properly formed collection or create the new attributes with the `serializeData` method on the `ItemView`.

In the first case, you will do something like this:

```
var SomeCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "your-template-name",
    childViewContainer: select
});

var SomeItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "your-other-template",
    tagName: 'option'
});

// This collection can be retrieved from a database or anywhere else
// Just make sure that the models have the fields you want
var myCollection = new Backbone.Collection([{id: "someid1", name: "name1"}, {id: "someid2", name: "name2"}]);

var view = new SomeCompositeView({collection: myCollection});
```

On the second case you'll have something similar but on the `ItemView` you'll have:

```
var SomeItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "your-other-template",
    tagName: 'option',
    serializeData: function () {
        return { someAttribute: "someValue" }
    }
}
```

Just remember that for this second approach, the `ItemView` has to have access to the values you are returning. `serializeData` is only for reformatting data or performing operations on the data that you cannot perform on the template. The template will only have access to the variables you are returning from `serializeData`, independently of the original model.

Comment: Thank your for the reply. There no problem per se, everything works like it's supposed to. I can write `%option{:value => "#{@id}"} = @name` in my `ItemView` template and both @id and @name will be parsed and displayed properly. However in this case each `%option{:value => "#{@id}"} = @name` will be wrapped in a `div` created by Marionette, which will ruin the `slecect>options` HTML structure. So I need to find the way to pass both content _and_ attributes inside a _single_ element.

Comment: It sounds really weird. Could you add the rest of your code (where you create the collection, how you pass it to the view, etc)? Also, in your original question you didn't mention anything about the wrapping `div`, but that also sounds like there is something wrong with your code because if you provide `tagName` for both views it should not create a `div`